# Pushing info from form values to object not working

Tags: javascript, forms, object, push

I am having trouble with getting the values of the form i have created with javascript to push into the object.

im in a project creating an addressbook and im stuck here and dont know what to do. So if anyone can help me with that!

The first part of the code is the object function I have created. And appends the contacts to li's.
The second part of the code is to create a form, and loop a form with 5 input fields. 
The third and last part of the code is where I dont know what to do or how to do.

I need to get the values of the form and push is it in to the object (as arguments?) to ( contacts = []; ) but isnt working.

```
//Contactlist funktion
function Contact(fname, lname, address, email, phone) { 
    this.fname = fname;
    this.lname = lname;
    this.address = address;
    this.email = email;
    this.phone = phone;
}

//The contacts
var contacts = [];


// Appending the objects
function theContacts() {
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],
        outerUL = document.createElement('ul'),
        length = contacts.length;
    outerUL.className = 'contactlist';
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        var cont = contacts[i],
            li = document.createElement('li'),
            ul = document.createElement('ul');
        li.className = 'contact'; li.innerHTML = cont.fname + ' ' + cont.lname;
        ul.className = 'infos';
        for (var key in cont) {
            var info = document.createElement('li');
            info.className = key;
            info.innerHTML = cont[key];
            ul.appendChild(info);
        }
        li.appendChild(ul); outerUL.appendChild(li);
    }
    body.appendChild(outerUL);            

}
```

and then I have this part...

```
// Calling the object

function addForms(){
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    var myArray = ['fnameValue', 'lnameValue', 'addressValue', 'emailValue', 'phoneValue'];
    var texts = ['First Name: ', 'Last Name: ', 'Address: ', 'Email: ', 'Phone: '];

// Create a loop of 5 
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    var input = document.createElement('input');
    var newlabel = document.createElement('label');
//        newlabel.setAttribute('for', myArray[i]);
        newlabel.innerHTML = texts[i];
    form.appendChild(newlabel);
    input.setAttribute('type','text');
    input.setAttribute('id', myArray[i]);

    // adds the input's to the form.
    form.appendChild(input);
    }

    // adds the forms to the body
    body.appendChild(form);

    // Add Contact Button
    var addContact = document.createElement('input')
        addContact.setAttribute('type', 'button')
        addContact.setAttribute('id', 'addContact')
        addContact.setAttribute('value', 'Add Contact')
        form.appendChild(addContact);

    var knapp = document.getElementById('addContact');
        knapp.addEventListener('click', addNewContact)      
}
```

This is the part that i am stuck with, and well maybe i need to modify the code above too, idk.. 
Please help me.

```
function addNewContact() {
        var input1 = document.getElementById('fnameValue').value;
        var input2 = document.getElementById('lnameValue').value;
        var input3 = document.getElementById('addressValue').value;
        var input4 = document.getElementById('emailValue').value;
        var input5 = document.getElementById('phoneValue').value;
    contacts.push(input1, input2, input3, input4, input5);    
    }

document.getElementById("newButton").addEventListener("click", addForms);
```

Comment: You've an infinite function call in `addNewContact`. Browsers will stuck on that too : ). How is `Contact` constructor function related? Looks like you are not using it at all.

Comment: Ok, I see. Thanks! Well, isnt it related to the var contacts [] ? If you can help me there because Im not pro in this. @Teemu

Comment: Well, the root of your problems is that you've multiple elements with a same `id`. In `addForm` you're creating elements within a loop with fixed value. This works when you click `#newButton` only once. After a second click the function creates more elements with the same `id`s. I'd wrap the inputs within a `div`, and give a unique `id` to that div (add a number after the body of the `id`). Then keep track of the current `id`, and in `addNewContact` read inputs from that particular `div`.

Comment: you have to call your constructor function like so: `contacts.push(new Contact(input1, input2...))` for it to do anything.

Comment: Didnt think of that issue.. Can you please help me out here and tell me what to do or anything, beacause im stuck here and dont know what to do. And im literally hitting my head to the table because I dont know what to do. @Teemu

Comment: Thanks @JaredSmith, i did change to that and now I can see that there is contacts in the console when i search for contacts. But i dont know why they doesnt show on the HTML?

Comment: Uhh... there's a lot of work. Try to get rid of the `id`s of the dynamically created elements altogether, and use Collections/NodeLists produced by `getElementsByXXXX` methods or `document.querySelectorAll`. And don't forget, what Jared has said.

Comment: because you never call the function `theContacts()` that would add them. At least not in the code you've posted. Also if you find teemu's and my info helpful, kindly consider upvoting :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got some things sorted out, but there is still some work cut out. Anyway, I got the  `addNewContact()` method working after attaching the event listener directly to  the button:

```
addContact.addEventListener('click', addNewContact, false);
```

In the `addNewContact()` method I emptied the contacts array before adding any elements to it, because otherwise after the second 'addContact' button click there'll be twice as many elements in the array.

```
contacts.length = 0; //this empties the array
contacts.push(input1, input2, input3, input4, input5);
```

Alternatively, instead of doing the above, I tried directly adding a Contact object into contacts array:

```
contacts.push( new Contact(input1, input2, input3, input4, input5) );
```

Finally, like Teemu suggested I removed the infinite loop call in the `addNewContact()` method

After I did those things, I got `theContacts()` method working partly, which was called in the `addNewContact()` method.  [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jyrkim/L88d552r/)

Comment: Thanks Jyrkim! I used the second one contacts.push(new Contact(.....)); and with the code you fixed and now it works as it should! Thanks for that! :)